# Asking Meta which Stack Exchange site should be used

Tags: discussion

Can users post a question on the meta to discuss their question on the main site (i.e.,http://superuser.com ) for example "Should I ask this question on askubuntu or for here on superuser ?" or is it better to ask "Why there is no response on my  question" ? I've done this twice on the meta, but I want to be sure if this is approved way?

Comment: Approved AFAIK..but not for Super user.. only Ask Ubuntu here...

Comment: @Venki what is the meaning of AFAIK?

Comment: AFAIK : As far as I know ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this part of the site is to help people figure out how to best use Ask Ubuntu, so ask away!